# Geometric interpretation of a definite integral of $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$? (Volume? Area?)

Tags: calculus

If we define $g:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $g(x)=2x$, then we can interpret e.g. $\int ^5_2g(x)dx$ as an area.

Now suppose we define $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ by $f(x)=(2x,3x^2)$. Is there any similar geometric interpretation of $\int ^5_2f(x)dx=(\int ^5_2 2x dx,\int ^5_2 3x^2 dx)$ as a volume/area?

If there's any such geometric interpretation, then what would the volume/area be in the figure below (drawn in [CalcPlot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html?type=spacecurve;spacecurve=curve;x=t;y=2t;z=3t%5E2;visible=true;width=2;view=0;tmin=-10;tmax=10;tsteps=100;color=rgb(255,0,0);showtrace=false;tval=0;constcol=false;twod=false;arrows=0;showpt=true;trace=true;vel=true;acc=true;osc=false;k=false;repeat=false;bounce=false;dashed=false;tanline=false;dropcurtain=false;showtvector=false;shownvector=false;showbvector=false;showtnbeqs=false;showtnblabels=false;showoscplane=false;showrectplane=false;shownormplane=false;optimizecurve=true;maxjointangle=10&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=false;anaglyph=-1;center=1.0202849917410135,2.636423523136987,9.592095159153967,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=-0.03280817281431464,0.9646086794515346,-0.26163661693912904,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=false;showaxes=true;showticks=true;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=true;gridplanes=true;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-2;xmax=2;ymin=-2;ymax=2;zmin=-2;zmax=2;xscale=1;yscale=1;zscale=1;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=1;tracemode=0;keep2d=false;zoom=0.961333))?

[image]

Comment: Uhm.. How do you calculate $\int_{2}^{5}(2x,3x^{2}){\rm d}x$? What's the definition?

Comment: There is no one fixed interpretation. The interpretation depends on the situation. For example, if I think of $f$ as describing the velocity vector of a particle as it undergoes motion in the plane, then $\int_2^5f$ can be interpreted as the change in position of the particle. See [Visualization of double integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4118048/568204) for what I mean by "interpretation depends on the situation". Sure, in that link, I mainly address the interpretation of different domains, while you're asking about the target spaces, but the main message stays the same.

Comment: or of course, the most straight forward interpretation is to think of the $(x,y,z)$ coordinate system, and think of the function $f$ as giving two functions $f_1,f_2:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, and think of $f_1$ as "living on the $y$-axis" and $f_2$ as "living on the $z$-axis". Then, $\int_2^5f(x)\,dx$ can be thought of as the vector consisting of the appropriate areas bounded by the graphs of $f_1$ and $f_2$. This interpretation may sound obvious, but that just goes to show that there is no one fixed interpretation of integrals.

Comment: *the vector consisting of the appropriate areas* --- I'm not sure what you mean by this? I thought a vector is a 1D object (like a line), while an area is a 2D object. If so, then how can a vector consist of areas?

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting my sentence. All I meant is that a vector in $\Bbb{R}^2$ means an ordered tuple of numbers. So, $\int_2^5f= \left(\int_2^5f_1, \int_2^5f_2\right)$ is a tuple of numbers. The first entry of the tuple is the number $\int_2^5f_1$, which one can think of as the signed area bounded by the graph of $f_1$ (which you draw on the $x$-$y$ plane) and the $x$-axis from $x=2$ to $x=5$. The second entry of the tuple $\int_2^5f_2$, which again can be thought of as the area bounded by the graph of $f_2$ in such and such region. Hence, we have a vector whose components are areas.