# Interpretation of the double integral over a region

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, area

I am studying multivariable calculus, and I came up with a doub that I cannot solve, or I believe I udnerstood wrong.

Say I have to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_T (x^2 + y)\ \text{d}x\text{d}y$$

Where $T$ is a well defined region (for example $T = \{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2; 0\leq x \leq 1,\ 1\leq y \leq 2\}$).

Now, I understood the double integration is mostly used to calculate areas of given regions or shapes. For example, the above integral alone, that is

$$\int_T \text{d}x\text{d}y$$

Will give me the area of the region $T$, which by the way is a square. So fine so far.

My question is: what does exactly mean to calculate the integral of $x^2 + y$ over this region?
$x^2 + y$ defines a region too, a shape (right?), yet not exactly since I expect a shape to be defined by a function $f(x, y) = 0$, not just $f(x, y)$.

I know it may be a stupid question, but I need to get those suble things to touch what I am studying, and my notes are not that useful. Thank you!

Comment: My biggest suggestion to you is to not get bogged down by one interpretation of an integral. There are several possible ways to interpret the numerical quantity obtained by integrating a function over a region. See [Visualization of double integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4118048/568204) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The integral I of x^2+y can only be thought of related to a region (other than T) by considering a set in 3D: in the simple case of a positive function (which is true in your situation) you get the volume of the set of points (x,y,z) such that (x,y) belongs to T and 0 <= z <= the integrand, i.e. 0 <= z <= x^2+y in your case. Forget your other considerations