# Visual Representation of the Line Integral

Tags: integration, line-integrals

**I am trying to better understand the visual interpretation of a Line Integral.**

We are all told that a classic integral of a function represents the area under that function between two certain points - but I am trying to now extend this this visual to a line integral.

For example, suppose I want to integrate the function $f(x) = 2x^2$ over the line segment $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Intuitively, without trying to evaluate the line integral, here is my attempts to represent the line integral (Python code):

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f1(x):
    return 2*x**2

def f2(x):
    return x**2 + x**2

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

y1 = f1(x)
y2 = f2(x)

x_line = np.array([0, 1])
y_line1 = np.array([0, 1])
y_line2 = np.array([0, 2])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

# Attempt 1
axs[0].plot(x, y1, label='Function: $f(x) = 2x^2$', color='blue')
axs[0].plot(x_line, y_line1, label='Line Segment', color='red')

y_line_interp1 = np.interp(x, x_line, y_line1)

# Shade the area between the blue curve and the red line
axs[0].fill_between(x, y1, y_line_interp1, where=(y1 >= y_line_interp1), color='green', alpha=0.3)
axs[0].fill_between(x, y1, y_line_interp1, where=(y1 <= y_line_interp1), color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Line Integral')

axs[0].set_xlabel('x')
axs[0].set_ylabel('y')
axs[0].set_title('Attempt 1: Plot of $f(x) = 2x^2$ and Line Integral')
axs[0].legend()

# Attempt 2
axs[1].plot(x, y2, label='Function: $f(x) = x^2 + x^2$', color='blue')
axs[1].plot(x_line, y_line2, label='Line Segment', color='red')

# Shade the area under the curve
axs[1].fill_between(x, y2, color='green', alpha=0.3, label='Standard Integral')

axs[1].set_xlabel('x')
axs[1].set_ylabel('y')
axs[1].set_title('Attempt 2: Plot of $f(x) = 2x^2$ and Standard Integral')
axs[1].legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**My Question:**  I think Attempt 1 corresponds to the Line Integral whereas Attempt 2 corresponds to the Classic Integral. **Have I correctly identified the area corresponding to the Line Integral?**

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** As per the comments from  @Anton Vrdoljak, the titles on both graphs have now been changed. As such, they should now be correct (?)

Comment: Perhaps you have to swap titles for your plots.

Comment: Usually a line integral is defined over a multivariable function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's intuitive, because it's the area underneath the graph and a certain curve $\gamma$. The line integral in $\mathbb{R}$ is just the regular definite integral.

Comment: Have you seen L.Vieira's [animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#/media/File:Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif) on Wikipedia?

Comment: @ 
Anton Vrdoljak: thank you! i will do this right now!

Comment: @  user170231: thank you for your reply! I saw this animation but it was a bit too complicated for me to follow ... I wanted to make a simpler visualization to help me understand. thank you so much!

Comment: *“We are all told that a classic integral of a function represents the area under that function between two certain points”* well that is only one possible interpretation and it isn’t always the best one. Not everything is about areas/volumes (for line integrals you *can* try to relate it to areas under some curve but doesn’t mean you *should*). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4118048/568204) for similar remarks. Besides, what you have currently written doesn’t make sense; you can’t integrate a function from reals to reals over a line segment in the plane.

Comment: @ peek-a-boo: thank you so  much for your reply! I will read the link you have posted for more information.